# Проверка на одинаковые значения двух массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть два массива которые нужно сверить на одинаковые элементы, если массивы одинаковые то вернуть true (независимо от того в каком порядке значения)

a = [1, 3, 5] , b = [5, 1, 3], c = [1, 3]
a === b // true 
a === c // false

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/compare-arrays-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify(a.sort()) === JSON.stringify(b.sort())
```